# Macro redefinition problem in C++ header file

Tags: c++, macros

When I try to run the following header

https://github.com/marmalade/glib/blob/master/glibconfig.h

in Microsoft Visual Studio, I get the following error: 'G_CAN_INLINE': macro redefinition. What is the reason for this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because of: L114-L118

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post code examples (minimal reproducible example if possible) as text (perhaps in addition to links) so that your question remains useful even if the links are dead.

Comment: @JaziriRami and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually a trick for this which might work for you.  What you can do is this:

1. Comment out the `#define`(s) for `G_CAN_INLINE` in `glibconfig.h` (make a copy first!).
2. After the relevant `#include`, add (temporarily) the following line to the source file that is generating the compiler error:

`int any_old_variable_name = G_CAN_INLINE;`

3. Give Intellisense a moment to catch up.
4. Right-click on `G_CAN_INLINE` and select 'Go To Definition'.

With a bit of luck, VS will then show you where that macro is (also) being defined and that should help you figure out what to do.

Having said which, `G_CAN_INLINE` doesn't look to be all that important.  You will probably find that you can just `#undef` it before you include `glibconfig`.